# How to use Forecast in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to use forecast in Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1052.htm#OLADM822

I have Oracle Standard Edition One but am not able to find a relevant example. Can you tell me how to use forecast in select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's additional feature for Oracle EE as I know. So you should have EE and buy this [option](https://shop.oracle.com/apex/product?p1=oracleolap&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&intcmp=ocom_oracleolap) depends on your version of Oracle